# Push notification flutter and laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, push-notification

How to make notifications with flutter **without** using firebase? I am using laravel for the backend and phpmyadmin for the database.

Comment: Hi! You should checkout pusher, a package for real time applications. This will make it possible for you to send notifications from the backend to the end-user. If you google. Google "pusher flutter". There should also be a package for Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Amplify for push notifications,
check out this link.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/getting-started-with-push-notifications-using-aws-amplify/